# iPod less than 1 year old battery life

Tags: battery, ipod

My less than 1 year old iPod touch (A1421) lasts about 8 hours with no use other than listening to podcasts.

Is this level low enough to justify an in-warranty battery replacement?

If so, do I need to do anything to provide proof or will they just set it to play and see the power gone after 8-9 hours?

Comment: These are all good questions to ask of an employee at an Apple Store

Comment: I added more detail. The store is a 1 hour round trip. I was hoping to find an answer here (even a confidence level) before going to the store. A "don't bother unless really" or "anything less than 20 audio hours and they should replace" was what I expected. I'd think this would be a legitimate question.

Comment: What version of iOS?  The first thing apple will do is make sure you've updated.   Also Settings > Usage > Battery Usage may give some clues.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/is-there-a-battery-conditioner-for-an-ipod-touch?rq=1 has some additional information (but isn't really a duplicate)

Comment: Yes 8.3 latest update . And I was monitoring setting/usage to make sure I wasn't falling asleep and using 10 hours without knowing. It confirms the sub 8 hr life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *may* be worth backing up your iPod and performing a factory restore. We recently had an iPad that would discharge to flat in around 8 hours, where the rest of the set would still be going strong a couple of days later. Restarting the unit made no difference. The last thing we decided to try before returning the iPad to our supplier was a factory restore, and it was this that returned the iPad power consumption back to normal.

Comment: Update - I tried this and it didn't work. My timing was awful, as I finally found the receipt and the 1 year had just passed. It's still useful, I just need to have a little battery handy, or access to an outlet. Next $75 off sale, I'll just grab a new one.